# The up to date rms cmb temperature variation

Tags: cosmology, photons, temperature, cosmic-microwave-background

I am searching online the most up-to-date result/data of cmb temperature variation, i.e.
$\sqrt{<\Delta T^2>} \mu K$

I sort of know it's of order $10\mu K$ and have seen it on an old first-year COBE data paper:
[Structure in the COBE differential microwave radiometer first-year maps](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1992ApJ...396L...1S/L000001.000.html)

Anyone please direct me to the up-to-date paper?

Comment: On what angular scale?

Comment: @RobJeffries based on any up-to-date experiment results, whatever their resolutions are.

Answer (score 3):

The best measurements of the CMB temperature fluctuations come from the Planck satellite.

The size of the fluctuations depends on the angular scale considered and is shown in the plot below (from [the ESA Planck website](http://sci.esa.int/planck/51555-planck-power-spectrum-of-temperature-fluctuations-in-the-cosmic-microwave-background/)).

[image: CMB temperature fluctuations from Planck]

Note the yaxis is in the conventional CMB units of $l(l+1)C_l/2\pi$, see [here](http://homepages.spa.umn.edu/~llrw/a5022/f14/CMB.pdf) for an explanation of the CMB power spectrum. The translation to simple temperature fluctuations as a function of angular scale is not straightforward, but the plot below corresponds roughly to rms temperature variations of 20 $\mu$K on large angular scales, rising to $\sim 80\mu$K on 1 degree scales, before falling again.